# highchecktree dynamically loading json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to dynamically load the checkbox items from my json response for that i have written below code but it is not working.

**Code:**

```
var mockData = { children: []};
if (parsedJSONObject.menuFunctions instanceof Array) {
                            $.each(parsedJSONObject.menuFunctions, function(i, obj) {
                             mockData.push({
                            item:{
                                     id: obj.menuId,
                                     menuDisplayName: obj.menuDisplayName,
                                     checked: false
                                      });
                                if (obj.hasOwnProperty("childMenus")) {
                                    var childMenu = "";
                                    if (obj.childMenus instanceof Array) {
                                        $.each(obj.childMenus, function(j, childObj) {
                                         mockData.children.push({
                                                        item:{
                                                id:childObj.menuId,
                                               menuDisplayName:childObj.menuDisplayName,
                                                         checked: false
                                      });
                                                                                            });
                                    } 
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        }
```

**My Json response:**

```
{"loginStatus":"Y","menuFunctions":[{"menuDisplayName":"My Document","menuId":"10127"},{"menuDisplayName":"Health 
Topic","menuId":"10128","parentMenuId":"-1"},{"menuDisplayName":"Alerts","menuId":"10129","parentMenuId":"-1"},{"childMenus":[{"menuDisplayName":"Conditions","menuId":"10131","parentMenuI
d":"10130"},{"menuDisplayName":"Procedures and 
Surgeries","menuId":"10132","parentMenuId":"10130"}]}
```

I tried the above code but nothing happen i don't know what i am doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: _"I tried the above code but nothing happen i don't know what i am doing wrong"_ I'm sorry, but this isn't a question. --- What do you mean by "nothing happen"? --- What are you trying to achieve? --- Be more specific.

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry for not being accurate. I am not able to push **children** into the same array, that is my issue. I am following this link http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Checkbox-Tree-View-highchecktree.html

Comment: Sorry. My comment was rushed. Forgive the tone.

Comment: @evolutionxbox No problems brother. Please help me if you can in anyway as i am stuck up here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in line mockdata.push

It should be like:

```
mockData.push({
item:{
    id: obj.menuId,
    menuDisplayName: obj.menuDisplayName,
    checked: false
}});
```

also incorrect in json response

Comment: Thanks for your help but my actual issue is want to put the childMenu in the same array as of Mainmenu.. I am not able to push **children** into the same array, that is my issue. I am following this link http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Checkbox-Tree-View-highchecktree.html